# How to move view up when there is no ImageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

[image: screenshot]

I am having a problem while designing a view through Storyboard in iOS.
I have added 2 Image Views to my view and a Label below them. But when there is no image, I have called the isHidden() method to each ImageViews, that should make Label to move up. Right?

But the Label is not moving up when I call it and it is showing an empty space as there is no image.

Can you tell me how can I fix this?

I am using Auto Layout and I have set Label to be below ImageView constraint.

Comment: what is your label width?

Comment: Label width is aligned leading to first image view and trailing to superview.

Comment: your two imageview and one label are into one view?

Comment: Yes. And I want to move label up when both of the images are empty. Like showing No images in your Album.

Comment: can you share screenshot that you require?

Comment: screenshot added.

Comment: Based on your screenshot this functionality is achieving by simply set label's text alignment. if imageview is nil then set right alignment and image is present then set left alignment. use this code label.textAlignment = .right in swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create IBObject of height constraint and instead of

```
isHidden()
```

write

```
constraintObject.constant = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use StackView. If you put your ImageViews and Label in stack view, when you hide each items, stack view will fill the spaces automatically.

[image]

if i hide the first one it will become like this:

[image]

and if i hide both of them, the result will become like this:

[image]